# Good way to coding on React-Native?

Tags: android, react.js, ios, react-native

I'm new on this field of coding, and I start to create by myself a project for iOS and Android. I'm a bit lost of how I supposed to organize my code, I saw different persons on YouTube doing their code by different way. I want help to know what is the best to how to write a code, who it will be understanding by people who can help me on my project on the futur. Thank you for your help, im coding in React Native.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (

    
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/Image/home-pic.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={styles.rectangle}>
          <Text style={styles.Text1}>T1</Text>
          <Text style={styles.Text2}>T2</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText1}>T-BUTTON1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.horizontalButtons}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText2}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText3}>Sign In</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
      flex: 1,
      width: wp('100%'),
      height: hp('100%'),
      resizeMode: 'cover',
    },
  rectangle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
    borderTopLeftRadius: hp('4%'),
    borderTopRightRadius: hp('4%'),
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    padding: hp('4.5%'),
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  Text1: {
    fontSize: hp('1.6%'),
    paddingVertical: hp('1%'),
    marginBottom: hp('1%'),
  },
  Text2: {
    fontSize: hp('2.0%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: hp('1%'),
  },
  buttonText1: {
    color: '#c0334b',
    fontSize: hp('1.6%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    paddingVertical: hp('1%'),
    marginBottom: hp('1%'),
  },
  horizontalButtons: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: hp('1%'),
  },  
  buttonText2: {
    backgroundColor: '#c0334b',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: hp('1.6%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    paddingVertical: hp('1.2%'),
    paddingHorizontal: wp('13%'),
    borderRadius: hp('2%'),
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: '#c0334b',
},
  buttonText3: {
    color: '#c0334b',
    fontSize: hp('1.6%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: hp('1.3%'),
    paddingHorizontal: wp('12%'),
    borderRadius: hp('2%'),
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: '#c0334b',
  },
});
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! In addition to the advice from Mast: It would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"